# Duda sobre Polimorfismo

Tags: java, poo, clase-abstracta

Tengo una clase abstracta Vendible(con atributos nombre, precio e identificador) y dos clases que heredan de ella Productos y Paquete, Paquete va a estar formado por un array de productos y la ventaja que tiene es que tiene un descuento del 20% sobre la suma de sus precios individuales.

¿Como me aseguro de que si cambia el precio de un producto cambia también el precio del paquete?

Este es el código que tengo:

```
public abstract class Vendible {
    protected String nombre;
    public double precio;
    protected String identificador;

    //Constructor Vendible//
    public abstract double getPrecio();

    public abstract void setPrecio(double precio);
    //No se si hacerlo abstracto
}
```

Y en la clase pack tengo este Override:

```
public double getPrecio(){
    double cont=0;
    for(int i=0; i<pack.size(); i++){
        cont+=pack.get(i).getPrecio();
    }
    precio=cont;
    return precio;
}
```

Comment: Puedes copiar tu código por favor

Comment: public abstract class Vendible {
 protected String nombre; 
 public double precio; 
 protected String identificador; 
 //Constructor Vendible//
 public abstract double getPrecio();
 public abstract void setPrecio(double precio); //No se si hacerlo abstracto    //Y en la clase pack tengo este Override//    public double getPrecio(){
  double cont=0;
  for(int i=0; i<pack.size(); i++){
   cont+=pack.get(i).getPrecio();
  }
  precio=cont;
  return precio;
 }

Comment: Pon tu código para ir sea más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Cual es la relación del título con la pregunta?

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que la variable `pack`de la clase `Paquete` es un array de `Productos` te aseguras de que va a tener un 20% sobre esos productos calculándo ese descuento al final de tu método `getPrecio()`.

También puedes crear para `Paquete` una variable de descuento y así te evitas poner "número mágicos" en el código. De esa forma quedaría así:

```
public class Paquete implements Vendible{
    double descuento = .8; //Se quedará el precio al 80%

    //Resto del código de Paquete

    @Override
    public double getPrecio(){
        double cont=0;
        for(int i=0; i<pack.size(); i++){
            cont+=pack.get(i).getPrecio();
        }
        precio=cont;

        return precio*descuento;//Al final de la suma se aplica el descuento
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, *`Vendible`* al ser una clase abstracta debe ser heredada con la palabra reservada `extends` y no con la palabra reservada `implements`, pues esta última se utiliza al implementar interfaces.

Luego debería declarar todos sus atributos como `protected` y manejarlos únicamente mediante los métodos **`set`** y **`get`** y darles una definición trivial, si lo deseas, ya que piensas heredarla.

Como mencionó @Awes0meM4n, una idea eficiente sería agregar el atributo *`descuento`* a tu clase `Paquete`- Sin embargo esta debería ser también utilizada a través de sus respectivos **setters** y **getters**, pues le da flexibilidad al atributo y te permitirá cambiar el porcentaje de descuento; aunado a lo anterior, debido al concepto de descuento el valor debería declararse como `.20` y no como `.80` que es el resultado de aplicar el descuento, sólo para apegarse al concepto de este.

Al final tus clases deberían ser de la siguiente manera:

```
public abstract class Vendible {
    protected String nombre;
    protected double precio;
    protected String identificador;

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public double getPrecio(){
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio){
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getIdentificador(){
        return identificador;
    }

    public void setIdentificador(String identificador){
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }
}
```

Y la clase Paquete:

```
public class Paquete extends Vendible{
    protected double descuento;
    protected List<Producto> pack;//O cualquier tipo de contenedor que desees utilizar

    public void setDescuento(double descuento){
        this.descuento = descuento;
    }

    public double getDescuento(){
        return descuento;
    }

    /**
        Aquí deberán ir los respectivos set y get de pack
    */

    @Override
    public double getPrecio(){
        double precio=0;
        for(int i=0; i<pack.size(); i++){
            precio += pack.get(i).getPrecio();
        }
        super.setPrecio(precio*(1-getDescuento()));
        return super.getPrecio();
    }
}
```

Comment: Una cosa, esto es un error: "En primer lugar, Vendible al ser una clase abstracta debe ser utilizada con la palabra reservada extends". Para declarar una clase como abstracta tiene que tener la palabra reservada abstract como bien tiene. Extends tiene que tenerlo la clase que hereda.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, en efecto debí ser más explícito al referirme que la palabra reservada "extends" se usa para heredar la clase padre.